# Finder sort by name generates unexpected result

Tags: finder

I have the following files in one of my folders

```
0.02248552322283664.txt 
0.0230501775260322.txt  
0.0242936049125664.txt  
0.0251569304235662.txt  
0.1320847497686747.txt
```

I want to use finder to sort them by "Name".

But the order looks so weird.

[image: finder sort by name]

Why doesn't `0.1320847497686747.txt` appear at the top row?

Why does it appear at the middle of the files?

`0.1` is larger than `0.0`. So `0.1320847497686747.txt` should appear either at the top or bottom of the file list.

How does the sort work under the hood?

Can I change the behavior of how Finder sorts the files?

My MacOS version is `12.5.1`.

Comment: It seems like that Finder puts the longest file name at the top of the file list.

Comment: It looks like it's treating the part before the first "." and the part after it as separate numbers, rather than a single number with a decimal part. 02248552322283664 = 2248552322283664 > 1320847497686747, so that one sorts as a higher number.